# Can you get fired before the first 2 years under a talent passport in France?

Tags: visa, france

I have a great offer to be hired in France under 'Talent Passport' but for some reason, the 'investors' ( not the CEO) think that the law is forcing them to keep me as an employee for two years when actually: 'The work authorization is linked to the French employer – the employee cannot change employers during the initial two years.

I cannot change roles, but they can fire me if I am not achieving the targets set for me, correct?

Can you please clarify this for me?

Comment: The employment visa is not an employment contracts. The company should always be able to act in its best interest. That is really an internal company policy issue (though employment laws in France are quite protective).

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the executives ( that never hired a foreigner) are trying to protect their interests which is what they need to do. However, the interpretation of the details of a talent passport in this particular matter is wrong. It is me who cannot resign, they can fire me any day of the week if they are not happy.

Comment: Why do you think you cannot resign? It's a job, not prison or slavery.

Comment: You can of course resign at any time, but your visa will probably run into trouble. The visa doesn’t give you the right to live and work in France for two years, but to live in France and work _for this company_ for two years.

Comment: I’d assume they can only fire you according to French law, which would be the same rules as for any French employee. That would definitely not be any day for no reason.

Comment: Hello everyone and thank you for your help. I believe I am expressing myself incorrectly. the 'Talent Passport' as my lawyer explained has a disadvantage; The work authorization is linked to the French employer – the employee cannot change employers during the initial two years. However, the executives at the company think that they cannot dismiss me for two years ( which is not the case). Can anybody confirm that I am correct in my analysis of the law for this particular visa? Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The work contract that the employer must provide to you in order to obtain a *passeport talent* visa is ruled by french laws as it would be for any employee in France. As such, there are provisions for ending the contract (from both parties) earlier than planned.

The main (and common) tool for ending the contract early in case of the employee actually not fitting the role is the *période d'essai* (https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1643).

> La période d'essai permet de s'assurer que le salarié embauché
> convient au poste sur lequel il a été recruté. Elle permet également
> au salarié d'apprécier si les fonctions occupées lui conviennent. Elle
> n'est pas obligatoire. Sa durée varie en fonction du type de contrat
> de travail : CDI, CDD ou contrat de travail temporaire (intérim). Sa
> durée varie également en fonction de la catégorie professionnelle du
> salarié. Elle peut être renouvelée ou rompue de manière anticipée,
> sous conditions.

Be aware that depending on several factors (including the type of work contract), this period can be several months long.

It is true that once this period is over, french law is protective to the employee and one cannot be easily fired without serious motives.